# Are QUERY and MATCH operators of elasticsearch SQL are the same operators of standard SQL?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Are QUERY and MATCH operators of elasticsearch SQL are the same operators of standard SQL ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-search.html#sql-functions-search-match

Comment: What, to you, is standard SQL? There are several versions of the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, none of which are fully implemented by any database engine. I'm pretty sure that neither `MATCH` nor `QUERY` are part of it, nor is it clear what you'd do with a "yes" or "no" answer. Elastic supports what Elastic supports, and other engines support whatever they support.

Comment: So why did elastic support SQL query syntax if it's not as the standard SQL?

Comment: Because "everyone" knows SQL, so many databases or database-like systems offer syntax that is SQL-like. Beyond the basics of `SELECT`, though, things start to vary widely -- engines don't agree on how identifiers should be quoted, what kind of string functions are available, etcetera etcetera. "Standard" SQL came as an effort to get the various SQL dialects to agree a little, an effort which has mostly failed (except for newer things like temporal tables, where vendors at least agreed to not all invent their own syntax again but adopt the standard if they implement the feature at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe full text searching is part of the SQL standard. These ops are full-text search ops. So AFAICS, the answer's no.